# Best online backup solution

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, backup

I'm looking for a good backup solution to use on our Windows2008 Server, we have just under a TB of data we need to backup weekly.

I've had a look around but anyones advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/). It is open-source and it supports Unix, Linux, Max, and Windows.

Comment: is it online? i dont see any cloud storage plugins directly?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-size-fits all for this type of thing. There are a lot of things to consider. Price per GB is the biggest one, which has its own caveats. Do you want de-dupe or compression? How much retention do you need? What are your backups? Exchange, SQL, Sharepoint? A lot of times those require an agent, which also cost extra.

There are a lot of companies like Carbonite or Mozy that promise unlimited backup for dirt cheap. What they don't tell you is that if you have a failure, and need all of your data STAT, that will cost you as well. If you need to recover say, 1GB or so, you will wait in a queue of others doing a restore.

When I was going down this road, it was over 2 weeks of research and calling companies and evaluating software.

Answer (score 1):

Mozy has a good online backup solution for servers at 50 cents a GB
http://mozy.com/pro

Comment: Mozy throttles connections pretty severely when you attempt to restore (as does Carbonite), so a 4GB restore will take several weeks (not even joking).

Comment: I have restored 200 GB in a day on Mozy. The Pro version is not throttled. The home version used to be but they claim it is not anymore

Comment: I've (recently) attempted to restore 2GB over MozyPro, and it downloads a few hundred MB and slows down to a couple of kb/s (on a 100Mbit uplink).

Answer (score 1):

I am using JungleDisk Server edition for my backups. works quite well. backing up about 500Gb total accross multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

[Evault](http://www.i365.com/products/cloud-storage-services/evault-saas/index.html) is an enterprise class backup solution provider with agents for all the major Windows server roles (SQL, Exchange, Sharepoint, File). It's not the cheapest, but I know it works from experience.

They offer a cloud based SAAS solution, as well as the option for you to buy the software and run it yourself.